# what are the attributes in Cals table mean

Tags: xslt

I've working on CALS tables and was stuck in a step. I've the below table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table frame="all">
<tgroup cols="2">
<colspec colnum="1" colname="col1" colwidth="2*"/>
<colspec colnum="2" colname="col2" colwidth="16*"/>
<tbody>
<row>
<entry align="center" valign="top" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para><content-style font-style="bold">A</content-style></para></entry>
<entry align="left" valign="top" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para><content-style font-style="bold">Board Matters</content-style></para></entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry align="center" valign="top" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para></para></entry>
<entry align="left" valign="top" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para></para></entry>
</row>
<row>
<entry align="center" valign="top" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para><content-style font-style="bold">2</content-style></para></entry>
<entry align="left" valign="top" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para><content-style font-style="bold">Board composition and balance</content-style> <content-style font-style="bolditalic">(strong and independent board with no dominant</content-style><content-style font-style="bolditalic" format="strikethrough">e</content-style> <content-style font-style="bolditalic">individual(s))</content-style></para></entry>
</row>
</tbody>
</tgroup>
</table>
```

and the below XSLT.

```
    <xsl:template name="table" match="table">

<xsl:if test="./title/page">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./title/page"/>
    </xsl:if>    

<div class="figure">
<div class="figure-title">
<xsl:value-of select="./title"/>
</div>
</div>
        <table class="frame-{current()/@frame}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::title)]"/>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="tgroup">
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::tgroup)">
            <xsl:if test="@colsep|@rowsep|@align|cols">

            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
        <colgroup>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=".//colspec" />
        </colgroup>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::colspec|self::tfoot/*)]" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="tbody" match="tgroup/tbody">
        <tbody>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/row">
                <xsl:call-template name="row" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tbody>

        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::tfoot">
       <tfoot class="foot">

            <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::tfoot"/>
        </tfoot>
        </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="thead" match="tgroup/thead">
        <thead>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/row">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current()/entry">
                        <xsl:call-template name="headentry" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </thead>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="box">
<div class="box">
<div class="title">
<xsl:value-of select="./title"/>
</div>
<xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::title)]"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="colspec" match="colspec">

        <xsl:variable name="b">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../colspec/number(substring-before(@colwidth,'*')))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <col class="colname-{current()/@colname} colwidth-{concat(format-number( number(substring-before(@colwidth,'*')) div $b * 100,'##'),'%')}" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</col>]]></xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="row" match="row">
    <xsl:if test="./entry/*/page">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./entry/*/page"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="parent::tfoot">

                        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/entry">
                <xsl:call-template name="entry" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>

                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
<tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/entry">
                <xsl:call-template name="entry" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>                   
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="entry" name="entry">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="./@namest">
                <xsl:variable name="namest" select="@namest"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nameend" select="@nameend"/>
                <xsl:variable name="namestPos" select="count(ancestor::tgroup/colspec[@colname=$namest]/preceding-sibling::colspec)"/>
                <xsl:variable name="nameendPos" select="count(ancestor::tgroup/colspec[@colname=$nameend]/preceding-sibling::colspec)"/>

                <td colspan="{$nameendPos - $namestPos + 1}" align="{@align}">

                                                <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="@align and ./@morerows">
                <td align="{@align}" rowspan="{number(./@morerows)+1}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="para">
                        <div class="para">
                                                       <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="./@morerows and not(./@align)">
                <td rowspan="{number(./@morerows)+1}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="para">
                        <div class="para">
                                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="not(./@morerows) and ./@align">
                <td align="{@align}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="para">
                        <div class="para">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>
                    <xsl:for-each select="para">

                        <div class="para">
                                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(self::page)]"/>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="headentry">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@align">
                <td class="align-{@align}">
                    <xsl:if test="translate(current()/@namest,'col','') != translate(current()/@nameend,'col','')">
                        <xsl:variable name="colspan">
                            <xsl:value-of select="xs:integer(translate(current()/@nameend,'col','')) - xs:integer(translate(current()/@namest,'col','')) + 1" />
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$colspan">
                            </xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="para">
                        <div class="para">
                            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>
                    <xsl:if test="translate(current()/@namest,'col','') != translate(current()/@nameend,'col','')">
                        <xsl:variable name="colspan">
                            <!--   <xsl:value-of select="translate(current()/@nameend,'col','') - translate(current()/@namest,'col','') + 1" />-->
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$colspan">
                            </xsl:value-of>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="para">
                        <div class="para">
                            <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
                        </div>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

here when i run the XSLT everything is fine but i was having a problem with the below XML part.

```
<row>
    <entry align="center" valign="top" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para></para></entry>
    <entry align="left" valign="top" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para></para></entry>
    </row>
```

In the output i need a blank row, and it is getting generated, but it looks more like two lines on one another with no gap. as shown below.

[image]

But i actually i need some gap between these lines like below.[image]

please let me know how can i get this done, I want to know how i can make use of the `colsep` and `rowsep` in my XSLT.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a non-breaking space as a content in your empty `para`. More like

```
<row>
    <entry align="center" valign="top" colname="col1" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para>&#x00A0;</para></entry>
    <entry align="left" valign="top" colname="col2" colsep="1" rowsep="1"><para>&#x00A0;</para></entry>
</row>
```

Comment: Hi @Joel, Thanks for the response, i just want to know if this can be done in XSLT by using `rowsep` and `colsep`, also i would like to know, what these are for. Thanks again

Comment: `rowsep` and `colsep` are just but borders, if set to 1.